# sort events based on event date custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, sort, events

I'm trying to list events (custom posttype 'kurs') by event date, which are stored as custom fields ('dato').

My loop so far looks like this:

```
<ul>  
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'kurs' ) ); ?>

<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<li><?php the_title( '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a>' ); ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

What I need is a list of post(event)-titles from today forward in the future...

Comment: this has been asked like 345345325932845 times. simply store the date as a UNIX timestamp and use the `orderby => 'meta_value_num'` argument...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `meta_key` to sort your events in your array. Like so:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'kurs', 'meta_key' => 'dato', 'order_by' => 'meta_value', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Cool, that works, thanks for the fast reply! Only one more thing: how to display just future events?

Comment: Do you mean that after the date is passed you want them to not be there anymore? The best way would be to use post expiration that sets a published event to "draft" or "trash". I use this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-expirator/ . Also, since I did correctly answer your original question, mark it as correct so it shows up as answered.

Comment: This is what I mean, but I would like to use the already existing event date for this, otherwise I have to enter both event date and expiration date...

Comment: Not sure how to do that, I would post a new question.