# Wordpress Custom Content and Taxonomy's Archives

Tags: php

Ok so I have set up a custom content type: Event

I have then set up the custom taxonomies in hierarchical format for Event: Type

To display "event" posts in each "type", I'm using the template: taxonomy-type.php

I have then set up a widget "Custom Taxonomies Menu Widget" to list the "types" in one of my widget areas with a count for post in each type.

My issues:

Clicking one of them takes me to pages that don't match the "event" posts that should be there for that "type". (one of which, the party "type, shows no posts available even though I have some in that "type".

The count is not right for the posts in each category. (not that big of a deal compared)

Comment: Can we see some of your code please? Specifically, for the widget code you created (that seems to be where the problem is at based on your question) also `taxonomy-type.php`'s code might be useful to look at.

Comment: I'm using the plug-in "Custom Taxonomies Menu Widget". Could that be the issue? How can I just write my own?

Code for the taxonomy-type.php: https://gist.github.com/1653479

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the 'future' status is for posts that are not yet published and should not be used to mark events that occur in the future.

(I would recommend storing the event's data in the post meta, and then query/order by that post meta field. See [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7717/sort-events-based-on-event-date-custom-field) and [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38675/managing-event-dates-vs-published-dates-in-admin-custom-post-type))

Secondly, in your code you have these two lines:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 50, 'post_status' => 'future', 'order' => 'ASC' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

These completely override the default WordPress query which attempts to find 'published' events from your database that match the taxonomy term. (keep in mind 'future' events/posts are not considered 'published'.)

Your `$loop` query attempts to query the database for any 'event' that is not yet published, and since this over-rides the original query, it *should* show the same for every taxonomy term.

But you don't see this... (sometimes you see that there are no events). This is because of the conditional:

```
have_posts();
```

This is checking if the *orginal query* had any posts (i.e. are there any *published* events in this taxonomy term). It is not checking your current query (are there any future events?). To check your `$loop` query:

```
$loop->have_posts();
```

**How to merge rather than replace the query**

So, above I've said that you are over-riding the query that WordPress automatically does (looks for published events for that term). To include the taxonomy-term request in your new query, use the following trick:

Replace the two lines of your query with:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 50, 'post_status' => 'future', 'order' => 'ASC' );
//Merge with default query
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query,$args);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```